# Pass router parameters in Router.go()

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have a route to display user parameters: admin/users/details/:userID
In the template associated with this route I have "Back" button.

What is the best way to pass "return route path" to Router.go() and access it later in

```
Template.AdminUsersDetailsDetailsForm.events({
  "click #form-back-button": function(e, t) {
    e.preventDefault();     
    Router.go(PARAM.NAME, {});
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read about it [here](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#named-routes)

```
Router.route( '/admin/users/details/:userID', {
    name: 'admin.details',
    ...
} );


Template.AdminUsersDetailsDetailsForm.events({
  "click #form-back-button": function(e, t) {
    e.preventDefault();     
    Router.go('admin.details', {userId:'USER_ID'});
 }
```

---

You can generate url using:

```
Router.path('admin.details', {userId:'USER_ID'});
```

Comment: No, Default options is to pass all parameters in url, but I do not want to have return path inside url. I have shown that my url as "admin/users/details/:userID", and I want to pass additional parameter without url changing

Comment: So you should use `Router.path` - see updated answer.